# Storyboard Add-In for PowerPoint Unable to Load

Tags: vsto, ms-office

I recently installed the Office 2016 32 bit edition on my Windows 10 Enterprise OS.
I had a Story Board Add-In with PowerPoint - Office 2013, which now does not work.
I can see the Add-In but when I click any of its menu items, I get this message:

> TF86001: Team Foundation was unable to load the Office Add-In. This
>   may be caused by a Team Foundation Client installation problem or lack
>   of .Net programmability Support in the Office Application.
>
> For more information, see the following Microsoft website:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=220459.

So far I have tried the following steps:
- Reinstalled Office
- Repaired Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition
- Reinstalled "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)" from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48217

My suspicion is that since I have a 32 bit version of Office 2016 on my 64 bit OS, I would need a corresponding 32 bit version of Visual Studio Tools for Office. I was able to download the 32 bit edition of the software but it was blocked from being installed by the OS.

Any suggestions? Hate that storyboard no longer works :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

As I suspected, I had to first remove all 32 bit editions of Office, including Office Pro, Visio & SharePoint Designer.

Then I installed Office 64 bit edition.

- Went into File, Options, Add-Ins, Manage COM Addins.
- Added "Team Foundation Add-in" and bingo the Storyboard menu came back
- Click on "Storyboard Shapes" now works perfectly!

**Some Explanation**
It worked inb the Office 2013 32 bit version because Visual Studio Tools for Office allowed a 32 bit install. Since I installed the new version, VSTO ONLY allows the 64 version to be installed, i.e. it auto-detects your processor in the one installer file. Hence everything now has to be the 64 bit edition.

Comment: I have all products you described below on my work computer, 32 bit Office and I can start Storyboarding without any problems. On my home computer I can't.