# TF86001: Team Foundation was unable to load the Office Add-in

Tags: tfs, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010, powerpoint-2013, powerpoint-2016

I am having the following problem in Powerpoint 2016 when I click on the My Shapes icon on the storyboard ICON, any idea??

---

### Microsoft PowerPoint

TF86001: Team Foundation was unable to load the Office Add-in.

This may be caused by a Team Foundation Client installation problem or

lack of .NET Programmability Support in the Office Application.

### For more information, see the following Microsoft website: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=220459.

### OK

Comment: Have you done the obvious thing and clicked on the link and followed those troubleshooting steps?

Comment: yes I did, it says to repair VSTO but that didnt help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

but this one helped, I uninstaalled project 2013, then did a repair and it worked

[Storyboard Add-In for PowerPoint Unable to Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116739/storyboard-add-in-for-powerpoint-unable-to-load)

Comment: What did you repaired and what installation of Office do you have? 32-bit oder 64-bit?